# Computer no longer connecting wirelessly to router after Tomato clean install

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, tomato

I just installed Tomato firmware (details below) on my wireless-N router and everything appears to be working fine on the router's end. I can connect to the Internet properly with a wired (Ethernet) connection; in fact, that's how I posted this question.

What I cannot do is connect to the router wirelessly in any way. At first, I thought that something was wrong with my wireless security settings, because I read about some incompatibilities between Windows 7 and AES encryption. However, when I changed to TKIP, the issue persisted; when I switched from WPA2 Personal to WEP, the issue persisted; and **when I disabled wireless security entirely** — just for testing purposes — *the issue still persisted*.

My Internet search for this issue brought up a lot of old forum and mailing list posts, most of which were useless. The only one that seemed promising [suggested disabling Afterburner](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/54431-windows-7-laptop-wont-connect-wireless-w-tomato.html), but that came disabled by default on my install. I did try enabling it and then disabling it, but it had no apparent effect.

In case it's relevant: before I installed Tomato, I had a somewhat funky install of dd-wrt on the router. The first thing I did after installing Tomato was a full clean of the nvram through the web GUI's `Administration` → `Configuration` → `Restore Default Configuration` menu.

What do I have to do to get wireless running? I only have one computer available at the moment, but I'll try to update later if and when I can borrow more devices for testing.

Assorted specs:

> Linksys WRT160N v3
>   Tomato Firmware v1.28.9054 MIPSR2-beta K26 Mini
>   Linux kernel 2.6.22.19 and Broadcom Wireless Driver 5.10.147.0 updates

---

EDIT:
This is a computer issue, not a router issue. Two smartphones with wi-fi connections and another computer are all able to connect to the wireless network with no problems. However, the original computer was able to connect to the same router just fine before Tomato was installed. It has an internal wireless-B/G card, and I had Tomato set up to broadcast G-only, so it should have been compatible. What's the next step I should take in diagnosing the issue?

---

EDIT 2:
The computer in question was the only device in the house that wasn't set up for wireless-N, so I went out and bought a Wireless-N USB adapter and changed Tomato to be N-only. Using the new adapter, I get connection again. I suppose it's possible that the computer's OEM internal wireless card failed at exactly the same time that I installed Tomato on the router, but that would be one *heck* of a coincidence. I'll see if I can connect to some other G or B network next time I'm around one....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I swapped out my router and ended up with erratic networking behaviour in Windows 7. Web browsers would work, but some network dependant functions in programs would fail, like for example checking for updates, install add-on modules, loading iTunes Store, etc.

I the recalled having installed some network tools on this Windows PC at around the same time as the router upgrade. Since other computers on the same network were still working, it had to be something with this machine. But the Windows diagnostics were coming up with zero suggestions (except call a friend).

I ended up fixing it by performing a Winsock reset like this:

1. Start a command line as Administrator (type `cmd` into the Start
   menu search box, right-click on the found cmd.exe and select **Run as
   Administrator**)
2. In the shell window, type `netsh winsock reset` and
   press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Reboot

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer because it is the answer that helped me the most and it seems reasonably well-researched, but there is a caveat: I ended up doing a complete OS reinstall on the machine in question yesterday, so we'll never know what the actual issue was.

Comment: I hoped you removed the old wireless profile for your wifi network before you tried reconnecting .... If you didn't - there's your answer